# Facetgrid: how to space the xticks

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I have several histograms that I need to plot with seaborn / facetgrid. They each have their own different x/y axis scales.  I need to control the *space* between the ticks, so as to make it readable (right now they are all overlapping with each other). It won't help to force set the ticks, as each histogram has it's own scale. Here is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(style="ticks")
g = sns.FacetGrid(test, col="someCol", sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map(plt.hist, "someVal")
```

And this is what my histograms look like so far:

[image]

Comment: Iterate through `g.axes` and set the ticks the normal way you would on a matplotlib axes.

Comment: The (now deleted) answer by @error did at least show a way to solve the problem. Instead of deleting it, one could have simply edited, such that it wouldn't claim that this was the only possible solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest "make the plot bigger" is not an answer to "how can I control the space between the ticks".

Comment: Making the plot bigger is certainly a way to achieve what the question asks for, namely "control the space between the ticks, so as to make it readable".  I think we agree that the question itself is rather unspecific and making the plot bigger has undesireable side-effects - still no reason to say the answer is wrong (only its first sentence is indeed wrong). Why not handle this a bit more constructively, asking for clarification, linking to possible solutions, mark it as duplicate, etc.?

Comment: @mwaskom I think your idea is what I am looking for, but I don't know how to implement it. Do you have any sample code that I could use as a guide? Thank you very much!

Comment: @curious `ax.set_xticks`

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the ticks using this command :
`ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation = 90, labelsize = 20)`